# Writable many-to-many field in Django Rest Framework tries to save new child objects?

Tags: django-rest-framework

**Edit**: This is using django rest framework 2.3

I have a model structure that has 3 relationship "levels", one of which is many to many.

```
class Shipment(models.Model):
    stuff...

class ShipmentItem(models.Model):
    shipment = models.ForeignKey(Shipment)
    assets = models.ManyToMany(ShipmentAsset)

class ShipmentAsset(models.Model)
    serial_number = models.CharField(unique=True)
```

Using Django rest framework I want to be able to post to the "Shipment" endpoint with a payload that contains the `ShipmentItem`s for the `Shipment`, and the `ShipmentAsset`s for the `ShipmentItem`s ideally in one request.

The serializers are as follows..

```
class ShipmentAssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = ShipmentAsset
         field = ('id', 'serial_number', )


class ShipmentItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assets = ShipmentAssetSerializer(
        many=True, required=False, allow_add_remove=True,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ShipmentItem
        fields = ('id', 'assets', )


class ShipmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Shipment
        fields = (
            'id',
        )
```

The shipmentItem/Shipment relationship seems to work when I post to it with the assets part disabled, but when I try to post assets in the payload, It appears to be trying to create NEW assets with the posted data (I get an error regarding the unique constraint on the serial number) rather than creating a new many-to-many table object. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:  Important clarification, I'm using Django Rest Framework 2.3.13

Comment: I'm on Django Rest Framework 2.3, I don't think this applies? I tried the method from that ticket to no avail regardless.

Comment: This changes a lot so you want to add this to the question since 3.0 has been released 2.5 years ago and I don't remember anything from it any more.

Comment: Thanks, removed my duplication comment as it doesn't apply for DRF < 3.0